# Avoiding permissions popups in PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, outlook

I have a PowerShell script that inadvertently triggers popups asking the user for permission. For example, in the code:

```
$appt = $outlook.CreateItem("olAppointmentItem")
....
$appt.Send()
```

I have this PowerShell script running in a server that creates appointments, and the popups serve no purpose. How can I run my script without having Windows ask permission?

Comment: You should add Outlook as a tag to this question.  I suspect the permission prompt is originating from Outlook and not PowerShell.

Comment: Are you referring to the pop-up that prompts with "a program is trying to access Outlook blah blah blah", then gives option to allow or deny? If so, that is security with Outlook that I don't think can be disabled.

Comment: Also might want to include what version of Outlook you are working with...

Comment: I'm willing to work with any version of Outlook. If it's not possible to disable the popups, is there either another way to programmatically make a reservation, or programmatically click 'ok'? My objective is a server that makes calendar reservations in the Exchange server.

Comment: Can you add the pop-up you are getting or the exact text it contains. Might help folks know which one you are actually referring to and if it is possible to take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I found one, admittedly suboptimal, workaround for this problem. There is, almost unbelievably, but then again not really, a tool that clicks "yes" whenever a popup appears, the eponymous [Click Yes](http://www.contextmagic.com/express-clickyes/).